# Implement APNS in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, apple-push-notifications

I am doing Push Notification Service for Apple iphone/ipad. i got the server side code from http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/. it is working well.. but i have to implement it in Yii framework.

i have googled it. and got this
https://github.com/shiki/yii-apns

Here i need to set server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem, and device token dynamically at run time.I am new to yii..please help me how to use this component..

i have extracted all the files in components folder,and tried the below code.

```
    $obj=new SAPNS();
    $obj->providerCertificateFilePath="provider certificate file path";
    $obj->rootCertificationAuthorityFilePath="root certificate path";
    $obj1=$obj->getPushProvider();
```

but while calling getPushProvider method,i got the following error.

> include(ApnsPHP_Push.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

There is no such a file ApnsPHP_Push.php in ApnsPHP folder in my components folder.dont know in which part i did mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the guys has already wrapped up everything in a component, so you just need to put all the things in components directory and call the desired functions.

if you look at SAPNS.php its got a public property

```
$providerCertificateFilePath
```

and that will be the file path to your PEM file and other

```
$rootCertificationAuthorityFilePath
```

for secure certificate (if any).

After giving these values you have to call `getPushProvider` method that will give you an object for `ApnsPHP_Push` from here you can call this class normally as you do without framework.

Comment: thanx for your reply. but i got error while calling getPushProvider method. i have updated my questing with the code and error message i have got.

Comment: i think you did it well but since that guy has already made the auto loader so you just need to call
$obj->init() before calling
 $obj1=$obj->getPushProvider();